# Android 2.2 and 2.3 not support position:fixed

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

Android 2.2 and 2.3 does not support `position:fixed`. I need to make the header fixed, how can i accomplish this on Android 2.2 and 2.3 ?

Comment: Google? http://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

I found it out,

Just add "user-scalable=0" to the meta viewport tag.

```
Source: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/
```

It tells everything you need to know about fixed elements and mobile browsers :)